# Why does an async TypeScript function not return a Promise

Tags: typescript

In an Angular/TypeScript based web app there I have a component with a method to register a user. It uses an authentication service to register a user

```
async registerNewUser() {

  try {
    let value = await this.authService.registerRegular(this.user.email, this.user.password);
    console.log(value); // #2: value is undefined (I expect that it also prints the same result as in #1)
  }
  catch (err) {
    this.registerError = err;
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

The service method `registerRegular` looks as follows

```
async registerRegular(email, password): Promise<any> {
  var credentials = await this.firebaseAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  var promise = this.db.database.ref('users').child(credentials.user.uid).set({hello:"world"});
  console.log(promise); // #1: works. Promise is printed to console
  return promise;
}
```

**Problem:** I'm awaiting the result from `registerRegular` but it always returns `undefined` in #2. When I print the promise before returning it (#1) then I can see the printed promise object.

So it seems like that the promise of that async method is not returned. At least in the calling method it's never there.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What does the promise resolve to? I bet it's undefined.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: You shouldn't expect #2 to print the same thing as #1, because at #1 you have the promise, at #2 you have the awaited value of the promise. Try putting `console.log(await promise)` for line #1. I bet it's undefined, as @tkausl said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `value = await f()` is the synchronous version of `f().then((v) => value = v)`. i.e. you don't get a `Promise` when you `await`, you get the value that the `Promise` resolves to.

Comment: Ooohhh... Got it. Thanks.